# Scrollview in two Linearlayouts?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-scroll

I have 4 `TextView`s in my `Activity` and i am using `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. Top one `TextView` is kind of header (no need to scroll) next one is some kind of description which i want to make scrollable. 3rd one is again a heading (no scroll needed) and 4th is description (need to scroll).
I tried but only top `TextView` (header) and 2nd `TextView` (description) is being showed on the screen. Description is scrollable but the problem is, other two `TextView` are hidden.
Its kind of silly question to ask but i am kind of stuck here because i am new to android. Here is my `xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d0f7c9"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#b3cff4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvShow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Program Output"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d2b3f4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOutput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d0f7c9"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Top Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#b3cff4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle1"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Seconf Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#b3cff4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You made my day. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way I would probably do this is create two layouts. One being number 1 and 2 text view. The other layout being 3 and 4. and then in the first layout, include the second.

```
<include layout="@layout/layout2"/>
```

Something like this.
LAYOUT ONE

```
<linearlayout>
<text view>
<linearlayout>
<scrollview>
<textview>
</scrollview>
</linearlayout>

<include layout="@layout/layout2"/>

</linearlayout>
```

LAYOUT TWO

```
   <linearlayout>
    <text view>
    <linearlayout>
    <scrollview>
    <textview>
    </scrollview>
    </linearlayout>   
    </linear layout>
```